# Get Objective-C interface in Swift?

Tags: objective-c, swift, xcode

Is there a way to view the Objective-C interface that are available in swift?

For example, if I declare this Objective-C interface:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

#define STRING_CONSTANT  @"a_string_constant"
#define BOOL_CONSTANT YES

@interface ViewController : UIViewController
@end
```

I can access STRING_CONSTANT in Swift but not BOOL_CONSTANT.

Comment: "Navigate -> Jump to Generated Interface"

Comment: Thank you I have added this to the answer below

Comment: Here is an article that discusses *why*, and shows one method of making `#define`s such as a BOOL constant available to your Swift code: https://medium.com/@YogevSitton/from-objective-c-to-swift-use-complex-define-macros-in-swift-28cdff464fc7

Comment: @DonMag This article is a good example for a *Why not*. It explains a terrible Objective-C coding style and its translation into Swift.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Navigate -> Jump to Generated Interface"

[image]