# Where can I find objective c temp files for swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, objective-c-swift-bridge

All the swift files that are available for Objective C and can be found in swiftfilename-swift.h file.

Here we can see all the function declarations for swift methods.

I want to see the same for Objective-c functions, i.e. A swift file which list all objective c methods in single place

Where can I find?

Comment: Is this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45307269/get-objective-c-interface-in-swift what you are looking for?

Comment: Basically lets say there is a objective c class abhj .. i want to see its swift version .. to know about the method syntax .... even though intelli sense will help me sometimes if it doesn't then I would like to read it there by myself.

Comment: Can I see swift file declaration for objective c here ?